# Create one big lan with two access points

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking

I have one modem router (Arcadyan VRV8019AW22) provided by my ISP. From there, I have a Linksys LGS108P connected to three Linksys access points (one WAP54G, two LAPAC1200). I am trying to make one big LAN, so each device connected can see the others, no matter on which AP they are connected. Each AP has it's own IP, and the same subnet and gateway (the gateway is my ISPs IP).

I don't understand why, but if I am connected on the router, I can access every device in the LAN, but if I am connected, for example, AP1, I can only access the devices in the AP1, the rest of the devices are unreachable.

Comment: Please advise the make/model of your router and access points.

Comment: Based on the information you have provided so far (don't know make/model of router) the access points you have should be placing all devices attached to them on the right network.  Presumably, you have a connection from the LAN port of your router to the LGS108P, then the access points are connected to the LGS108P right?

Comment: Sorry, forgot the router, is an Arcadyan VRV8019AW22. And yes, the LGS108P is connected to a LAN port in the Arcadyan, the 3 APs are connected to LGS108P.

Comment: OK thanks for providing that info.  Can you please do the following:
Connect to each device in your network, and record the IP address you receive when you are connected.  And report back.

Comment: You mean the APs? Or every device in the network? The 3 APs have static IP: 192.168.1.50 (LAPAC1200), 192.168.1.251(LAPAC1200), 192.168.1.245 (WAP54G) with 255.255.255.0 as mask and 192.168.1.254 as gateway.

Comment: I mean, connect your client machine wirelessly to each access point and see what IP your client gets.  Your client should receive an IP on the 192.168.1.0/24 network, and be able to access the internet.  But, please check to be sure.

Comment: That would be a bit tricky because the devices are desktop pc, and the WiFi signal isn't strong enough to reach all the devices in the network, that's the reason we are using all these APs.

Comment: It doesn't have to be the same client, just any client connected to each AP.  Could be your phone too.  Just anything you can use to make sure you're getting an IP address (check the gateway and dns too) that you're expecting.

Comment: The client works fine, already just did a test with my laptop. Same IP, same mask and same gateway. Didn't try with my phone 'cause don't know how to see mask and gateway.

Comment: OK, so if you have a desktop connected to one AP, and a Laptop connected to the other AP, you can't communicate between them right?  Have you tried turning the firewall off on the devices to see if that's all it is?

Comment: I just realize: I have a device A connected to LAPAC1200 A. I can't reach device A if I am connected to LAPAC1200 B, and only LAPAC1200 B. If I am connected to the router, or the WAP54G, I can see device A just fine! Don't know what's going on...

Comment: Have you considered doing a factory reset on LAPAC1200 B and re-configuring the same as LAPAC1200 A?